# Single npm package with two commands

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a node.js package described by this JSON :

```
  "name": "mycommand",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "mycommand": "./index.js",
```

The `index.js` file contains this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const app = require('./src/app.js')
const { Logger } = require('./utils/Logger')
app.init()
```

And the `app.js` contains the code of a command line tool based on yargs.

Now, I would like to add a 2nd command in this package, but I don't know how should I proceed since there can be only one "main".

Anybody has an example somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `scripts` instead of `bin`?

> Now, I would like to add a 2nd command in this package, but I don't know how should I proceed since there can be only one "main".

The `bin` mapping has nothing to do with your main file.

Your command is getting symlinked, you can simply add more:

```
"bin": {
    "mycommand": "./index.js",
    "my-other-command": "./other-command.js",
```

Or you can use your `mycommand` and parse the arguments in the script app.js using `process.argv`:

https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/

Comment: No I don't think the "scripts" is relevant in my case, because I am not trying to execute some command when I run my node.js app.
What I am trying to build, is a set of command line tools (that would be run with npx), that are grouped in a single node.js package. So I really think "bin" is the appropriate field. But if I have multiple command line tools in my package, I don't know what the "main" property does.

Comment: @LiohAu the `main` has nothing to do with the `bin` - you can just add more files as in my example

Comment: So, does it means that I can omit the "main" property because it would be useless in my case ? 
Or do I have to keep that "main" pointing on "index.js" and add in that file the "require" commands for all the .js of all the command line tools that I am building ?

Comment: @LiohAu I think yes, just like that. If npm is showing a warning, you can add an empty JS script as main